# PHP: как сделать поиск по шаблону в значениях массива?

Tags: php, массивы, поиск

Есть условный массив с условными значениями типа:

```
01 => ssf g gf sfg;fjytryujfd gdf gf
02 => cvcb gbcd;xcvb xcvx dfg dfg
03 => dfg qwe fgggh;dfg fgh gh
```

Как видно, значения состоят из 2-х частей, разделённых знаком ;

Задача - сделать поиск на соответствие отдельно частям до ; и после ;

Со строгим поиском всё просто:

```
strstr($value, $text.";")
```

или

```
strstr($value, ";".$text)
```

А как сделать нестрогий поиск? Типа ";+(любое кол-во букв и пробелов)".$text

Пробовал писать регулярное выражение, но то ли пишу неправильно, то ли в RegExp нельзя вставить переменную, то ли функция strstr() в принципе не понимает регулярных выражений - такой вариант не помог.

Comment: Исправьте вопрос, это не совсем "нестрогий поиск", а точнее совсем не он. Корректнее было бы поиск "по шаблону", а сейчас название только вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($first, $second) = explode(";",$value);
```

И дальше любой вариант поиска в каждой части отдельно.

PS Ну и на счет регулярок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не сразу понял, что требуется, переписал ответ

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {

$text1 = preg_match("/.+;/", $value)
$text2 = preg_match("/\s*;.+/", $value)

}
```

Comment: То есть нужно из каждого значения создать дополнительный массив и поиск осуществлять уже по двухуровневому массиву? Имхо, не лучший вариант ((

Comment: А с preg_match() Вы можете помочь мне регулярку написать? Чтоб туда переменную $text включить. И чтоб всё работало ))

Comment: @humster_spb регулярка передается как обычный текстовый параметр, так что ничто не мешает ее собирать из любых кусков текста и их переменных. только не забывайте, что она должна заключаться в `/` или `~` или некоторые другие знаки.

Comment: @Mike да я это всё понимаю, но вот я пробовал писать что-то типа: $pattern = "/^;\w+\s+".$text."/"; Поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: @humster_spb `\w+\s+` говорит найди 1 и более букв за которыми идет  1 и более пробелов. Т.е. оно пропустит ровно 1 слово после точки с запятой. а его может там не быть и быть более 1 слова. так что `[\w\s]*` должна помочь, хотя может тупо написать `.*` что бы любые символы проверяла. И да, в $text разумеется не должно быть символов воспринимаемых регулярными выражениями как управляющие. А еще есть чудесный ресурс regex101.com там можно тестировать регулярки и видеть что они делают

Comment: @Mike да, вот такой паттерн сработал: "/;.*".$text."/"; Спасибо!!